# I messed up in Run/Debug Configuration and now unable to run a single line of code with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Here is the screen. Please tell me how to solve this.

[image]

And here it is saying main method is not found but I already written that in the class.

[image]

I tried to edit the configuration and messed it up. How do I fix this?

Comment: You might need to set the module correctly for IntelliJ to find the main class

Comment: Try changing the **MYCLASS** selection to **Main** in that open dialog

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: You have a class named `String` in your project. That class shadows the class `java.lang.String` and that means that you must either write your main method as `public static void main(java.lang.String...args)` or rename your class `String` to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class named `String` in your project. That class shadows the class `java.lang.String`.

That means that you must either write your main method as

```
public static void main(java.lang.String...args) {
}
```

or rename your class `String` to something else.